# Windows LocationApi

Tags: c++, windows-7, gps, geolocation, windows-locationapi

In my project i need location of Windows tablet. I develop my project in Windows7 with VisualStudio2013 and my target platform is Windows8.1. I both installed Windows7SDK and Windows8.1SDK.

In order to get my geographic location i tried to use Windows locationapi.lib.

when i call the following function:

```
if (SUCCEEDED(spLoc.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Location)))
{
}
```

this function is not succeeded both development environment and the target environment. so i cant continue into if statement.

do you have any idea if i should do something before calling this `CoCreateInstance` method?

PS:

if you know an easier way to get location with this platform or any sample code it would be helpful.

Comment: You calling CoInitialize ? What's the error you get?

Comment: Thanks @JoãoAugusto. That is why i cant get into. it is the first time that i work with Windows api so i didn't know that.